# Proof of Merkurjev's Theorem in "The Algebraic and Geometric Theory of Quadratic Forms"

Tags: quadratic-forms, algebraic-k-theory, short-exact-sequences

I just have a little question about the above mentioned proof. I'm thinking for days, but I'm still not getting it. 
For those who have the book (or want to look it up via google books etc.), it's the proof of theorem 46.1. 
I have actually no idea, why Proposition 46.4 guaranties the induction step. I'm not sure if it actually has something to do with $K$-Theory or if it's just some basic stuff. 
The induction hypothesis is the exactness of the sequence
\begin{align*}
0\to M_{n-1}/M_0\to^{\partial} \bigoplus_{\deg x\leq 2n-2}F(x)^\ast\to F^\ast 
\end{align*}
and Proposition 46.4 says, that $M_n/M_{n-1}$ is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{\deg x=2n}F(x)^\ast$ via $\partial_n$. Here, the $M_n$ define a filtration on $K_2F(C)$, where $C$ is the conic curve of a non-split quaternion algebra.
I see that this implies the exactness at the first term of 
\begin{align*}
0\to M_{n}/M_0\to^{\partial} \bigoplus_{\deg x\leq 2n}F(x)^\ast\to F^\ast,
\end{align*}
but I don't know why it is exact at the second term as well. I hope, there's someone here who can help me :-)

Nico

Edit:
I actually wanted to know the exactness at the second term

Comment: Red through it for around 1 hour. Just an idea, but do we have: $M_2/M_1 -> M_2/M_0 -> M_1/M_0$, exact (and so on)? This way we would get a diagram with vertical arrows and one could "subtract" the $F(x)^*$, with $deg(x) = 2n$ from the middle horizontal sequence, revealing that $ker(c) = \bigoplus F(x)^*$ with $deg(x) < 2$ for all $n$.

Comment: Since $M_n/M_0$ is isomorphic to $M_n/M_{n-1}\times M_{n-1}/M_0$ (that's some basic group theory), we in fact have a split exact sequence
\begin{align*}
0\to M_n/M_{n-1}\to M_n/M_0\to M_{n-1}/M_0\to 0
\end{align*}
containing your sequence.
But unfortunately, I don't see your diagram so far.

Comment: Well by this split sequence we can replace the first term of the 2nd sequence of your question with the middle term $M_n/M_{n-1} \times M_{n-1}/M_0$. Applying prop 46.4 we find that this gives $\bigoplus_{deg x = 2n} F(x)^* \times M_n/M_{n-1}$. Cant we now "subtract" the term $\bigoplus_{deg x = 2n} F(x)^*$ from the first and second term, just giving us the sequence for $n-1$? I admit this doesnt really give us the $ker$,$im$ of the maps. Maybe it helps to write down case n = 1, and check $ker(c)$